# Sqlite3 python in :memory: BD not removed (delete)

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, sqlite, memory

I have this code to create in memory DB :

```
 import sqlite3
 def Creat_In_Memory_DB():
     NewDbconn = sqlite3.connect('file:cachedb?mode=memory&cache=shared')
     NewDbconn.execute('''CREATE TABLE TestTable (ID   INT  PRIMARY KEY ,   FirstCo   TEXT   , SecCol   TEXT   )''')
     NewDbconn.execute('''INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES ("1","test1","test2")''')
     NewDbconn.commit()
     NewDbconn.close()

 Creat_In_Memory_DB()
```

When I call function Creat_In_Memory_DB() every thing goes OK , but when I close -exit- my app -program- the DB should be removed from memory(Because it is meant to be reserved temporarily) , my problem is ; when I start the app again I have this error :

```
OperationalError: table TestTable already exists
```

Even if I turned my PC off and restart it (to refresh memory) I still have the same error
It is look like that the DB has not removed I don't know why , I test it using this code (Even after turned my PC off and restart it to refresh memory):

```
 cursorM = NewDbconn.execute("SELECT * from TestTable ")
 for s in cursorM :
    print s[0] ,s[1] , s[2]
```

Out bout :

```
 1  test1  test2
```

So DB is really still exist ,why that is happened , and how can I remove the in memory DB after use it -close (exit)  my app - ?

Comment: You can _attach_ an in memory database to an in memory database as per [the doc](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html#details)

Answer (score 0):

Use `:memory:` instead of `file:cachedb?mode=memory&cache=shared`. Shared cache is an obsolete feature, and not encouraged by [SQLite official](https://www.sqlite.org/sharedcache.html#use_of_shared_cache_is_discouraged). Its existence is only for full backwards compatibility.

To use a real in-memory DB, change your connection URI to this:

```
NewDbconn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
```

SQLite3 will delete the database after closing its connections. I've tested it under Python 3.9.1.

Comment: I can't use :memory: because I need to create more than one db in memory so I have to create data bases in memory with names (cachedb1 , cachedb2 .... )This is to distinguish between them( data bases) when performing procedures during my program -app-

Comment: "Every :memory: database is distinct from every other. So, opening two database connections each with the filename ":memory:" will create two independent in-memory databases." https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html